# NVIDIA DIGITS: Get accuracy for segmented images

Tags: image-segmentation, nvidia-digits

I am trying to use NVIDIA DIGITS to perform image segmentation (by following [this](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/image-segmentation-using-digits-5/) article). After training the model, I was able to perform the segmentation on individual images.

Now I would like to give a list of test images and labeled images to DIGITS, and I want it to calculate accuracy for the input images. Is it possible to do it using DIGITS, if yes, then what are the steps? (options to select on framework while training/testing model, format of input file, folder structure, etc.)

Also, if DIGITS can't do it, then are there any other frameworks? (I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974167/how-to-test-accuracy-of-segmentation-algorithm) post, but it would be better if I can directly use some plug-and-play framework, to begin with)

Thanks!